# googletranslate.agi returning -1 everytime

Tags: return, asterisk, google-translate, agi

I am working on asterisk 11.0 and created a small dialplan of outgoing which converts text from english to other language

I have dowladed  googletranslate.agi ansd installed all the perl modules

My problem is that everytime i send some arguments to googletranslate.agi it returns -1

part of my dialplan

```
same => n,agi(googletranslate.agi,"${name}",fr)
same => n,Verbose(1,Translated text: ${gtranslation})
```

and my cli shows

```
Executing [3065700@outgoingsamplesfr:8] AGI("DAHDI/i1/09********-7", "googletranslate.agi,"akash",fr") in new stack
    -- Launched AGI Script /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/googletranslate.agi
    -- <DAHDI/i1/09********-7>AGI Script googletranslate.agi completed, returning 0
    -- Executing [3065700@outgoingsamplesfr:9] Verbose("DAHDI/i1/09971197459-7", "1,Translated text: -1") in new stack
 Translated text: -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to debug any agi script:

1) stop asterisk

2) start asterisk in your local console like

```
asterisk -vvvc
```

3) type "agi set debug on"

4) run your dialling to get agi execution.

If do like described above, you will get agi's error in your screen, also you will get agi execution debug which show all  script to asterisk communication.